# How to map an object that contains arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

i am new at javascript ,so i have an object that contains three arrays and i want to map map it and list my data

```
    const [Foods,setFoods] = useState({
      "id_food":[1,2,3],
      "name_food":["food1","food2","food3"],
      "quantity":[10,22,12]
  })
```

an imaginary code:

```
{ Foods.map((id,name,qte) =>(
    <p>{id}{name}{qte}</p>
 ))}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here.

Comment: i want to map the Foods object

Comment: map it to *what*?

Comment: to diplay it in a list ex ===>  1 food1 10

Comment: basically asking for a zip function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  Object.keys(Foods).forEach(prop => {
    Foods[prop].map((item) => console.log(item));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Foods.id_food.map((id, i) => {
    const name_food = Foods.name_food[i];
    const quantity = Foods.quantity[i];
    return  <AwesomeReactComponent key={id} nameFood={name_food} quantity={quantity}/>;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let mappedArray = Foods.id_food.map((ele, i) => {
    let name = Foods.name_food[i]
    let quantity = Foods.quantity[i]
    return {id: ele, name: name, quantity: quantity}
})
```

Output:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: "food1", quantity: 10}
1: {id: 2, name: "food2", quantity: 22}
2: {id: 3, name: "food3", quantity: 12}
```